# Convert .java to .smali

Tags: java, android, smali

As mentioned in the title I am trying to convert a java file into a .smali file, so these are the commands I am trying to launch from Android studio terminal:

`javac HelloWorld.java`

`dx --dex --output=classes.dex HelloWorld.class`

`baksmali classes.dex`

But when I launch the second command I get this error:

> bash: dx : command not found

Also, I've tried to compile my file directly to smali, by going to: `Build/compile to smali` on Android studio and this is the error I get:

> Error:Internal error: (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException) com.google.wireless.android.sdk.stats.IntellijIndexingStats$Index
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.wireless.android.sdk.stats.IntellijIndexingStats$Index>
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>     at com.intellij.util.indexing.counters.IndexCounters.(IndexCounters.java:34)
>     at com.intellij.util.indexing.impl.MapReduceIndex.(MapReduceIndex.java:86)
>     at org.jetbrains.jps.backwardRefs.index.CompilerReferenceIndex$CompilerMapReduceIndex.(CompilerReferenceIndex.java:214)
>     at org.jetbrains.jps.backwardRefs.index.CompilerReferenceIndex.(CompilerReferenceIndex.java:73)
>     at org.jetbrains.jps.backwardRefs.JavaCompilerBackwardReferenceIndex.(JavaCompilerBackwardReferenceIndex.java:12)
>     at org.jetbrains.jps.backwardRefs.JavaBackwardReferenceIndexWriter.initialize(JavaBackwardReferenceIndexWriter.java:74)
>     at org.jetbrains.jps.backwardRefs.JavaBackwardReferenceIndexBuilder.buildStarted(JavaBackwardReferenceIndexBuilder.java:40)
>     at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuild(IncProjectBuilder.java:358)
>     at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.build(IncProjectBuilder.java:178)
>     at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.runBuild(BuildRunner.java:138)
>     at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:302)
>     at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:135)
>     at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:229)
>     at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl.lambda$executeOnPooledThread$0(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:42)
>     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Any ideas on how I can make this work? or any other tool to convert .java to .smali?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

I just had to find the command dx which is located in `~/Android/Sdk/build-tools/$version` on Linux, but first make sure `android-sdk` is installed
(usually located in `~/android/sdk` on Linux) then run dx using

`./dx --dex --output=classes.dex path_to_source_file.class` if you are in the same directory as `dx`

Answer (score 0):

```java
public final boolean A0H(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, byte[] bArr) {
    3Hk A06;
    if (A0I(this.A0A.A00(bArr), "client_static_keypair_pwd_enc") && (A06 = A06(sharedPreferences)) != null && Arrays.equals(bArr, A06.A01())) {
        Log.i("AuthKeyStore/storedAndCanRead/3");
        return true;
    }
    Log.e(000.A0d("failed to store and read correct key", 000.A0n("EncryptedKeyHelper/reportEncryptedKeyHelperProblem/")), new RuntimeException());
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77040947/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).